# Get bottom-bar from panel extjs 4

Tags: extjs4, panel, toolbar

i have this panel with bbar:

```
panelModellazioneMS = new Ext.Panel({
   anchor: '100% 95%',
   layout: 'card',
   border: false,
   padding: '5 5 0 5',
   bbar: [ 
     {
    id: 'move-prevMS',
    text: 'Indietro',
    handler: function(btn) {..}
     }  ]
});
```

I would get the bbar of this panel in an extern function to disable. how can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is

```
panelModellazioneMS.query('#move-prevMS')[0]
```

But generally both tbar and bbar are stored in panelModellazioneMS.**dockedItems** and the second way is to get from that array.